# How to leave content unaffected when changing pages Django

Tags: python, django

So I have a song player/bar that I want to implement into my Django project. It is a Django partial/template component that will give the user all the basic controls such as playing, pausing, volume, and skipping.

When you changing pages and urls, obviously, everything in the HTML has to be re-rendered. This creates a problem for my music player since rendering would interrupt the processes of the music player (like playing music). What if there is a workaround to this? Where I can change pages without my player being affected and disrupted. I want my player to be similar to the players of Spotify or Soundcloud, where you literally have to exit the website or reload the page for the players to be interrupted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into JavaScript and AJAX. An option that's been around for a while is to use jQuery ([here's a random blog post about using it with Django](https://data-flair.training/blogs/ajax-in-django/)). More modern options would be React, Vue, Angular. These are more involved and will likely need you to learn a few other things along the way.